# Alternatives for integer list in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have a text file of approx 300MB, and each line is a (short) list of integer; most lines contain just 1 integer, the longest list contains 10. If I create a list of lists in Python, one list for each line, with the entries cast as `int`, I run into `MemoryErrors`... how can that be when I have 3GB of RAM? Environment is Python 2.7.3 on XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try list of tuples...  May help.

There is also an `array` module.